# absolute element under relative element leads to bizarre behavior under Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-transitions

This code runs as intended on Chrome:

Please hover over the blue ball for animation:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      border: thin solid #6D6;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    h2 {
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 100%;
      background-color: blue;
      height:100px;
      width: 100px;
      transition:all 1s ease-out;
      margin: auto;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    
    h2:hover {
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But the ball in the middle expands to the bottom in Firefox, and I have to set top or bottom in order to bring it back to its correct position. Is there is anyway to make it stay in the middle without assigning top and bottom value just like in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

A nice trick to center block elements in the middle of a relative positioned container, is using `top: 50%` and `transform: translateY(-50%)`.

It requires IE9+

```css
    .container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
      border: thin solid #6D6;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    h2 {
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 100%;
      background-color: blue;
      height: 300px;
      width: 200px;
      margin: auto;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
```

```html
  <div class='container'>
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
```

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/oujab44t/1/

Comment: its something that i dont want do,Extra positioning. as you can see chrome keeps the element in the middle while its expanding without any additional settings.Maybe it is Firefox's default behavior.

Comment: @RyVan Just because something behave a certain way in Chrome, doesn't mean this is the standard. The idea is to write code that runs the same everywhere. You're developing on Chrome, and complain that Firefox show things differently. If you had developed on Firefox in the first place, you wouldn't experience this problem. My advice remains. It's a good practice I've seen in many places. It's not a hack.

Comment: thanks man,but all i need to know is weather there is possibilities to do the similar in firefox.

Comment: @RyVan Can you rephrase the question please? What is it exactly you're after?

Comment: in chrome once i have set the blueball element to the middle .. it stays there even after the size increases and masking the top overflow and bottom overflow equally,in this case i dint need to assign margin-top or traslation to keep the element in the middle. But in firefox it expands to the bottom and it became eccentric unless i set the margin or positioning conditions..

Comment: I have added an animation to my script so you can see the difference in both browsers.

Comment: I can see the difference and it's actually very interesting. But I can't figure what you want. Are you just asking out of curiosity, why this method doesn't work well on Firefox? Or are you looking for a better cross-browser solution for your problem?

Comment: well the better cross browser solution would be to assigning conditions like margins or translation to the element instead of depending on the auto centric conditions. Its just a matter of curiosity and i don't wanna miss better solutions if there is any.

Comment: I tried researching about it, but couldn't find a lot of references. If you find the answer, I'd like to know as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Firefox. The circle is already expanded and skewed here. OP wants the circle to expand on hover, and I imagine they don't want it skewed, either.

Comment: @TylerH The skew was the code posted originally by Ry Van, same with the hover effect. My solution explains how to solve the problem with an alternative CSS that works on all modern browsers, but it doesn't explain why the problem exists in the first place. Disappointed about the -1, as this answer actually gives a correct answer to the problem.

Comment: @Narxx I see; in that case I've edited the answer so I can remove my downvote. But at this juncture the other issue remains: it doesn't answer the question as it was edited shortly after you answered.

Answer (score -4):

```
<head>
  <style>
  .container {
    to;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.